# Highcharts: how to set legend label name after chart created?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to change dynamically legend labels and I was surprised when I have not found method like `chart.legend.setLabels()`

I tried this

```
chart.legend.allItems[0].name = 'bla bla'
chart.legend.redraw()
```

nothing happend

tried to change options

```
chart.options.legend.labels[0].name = 'bla bla'
chart.redraw()
```

nothing happend

So is there way to change legend label name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use update() function

```
 chart.legend.allItems[0].update({name:'aaa'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bL5ZM/1/

Comment: I need to modify legend, not some custom created element

Comment: Update function is avaiable since 3.0, but you can update to the newest version ;)

Comment: Can we use update() function on any Highchart object? How can I change legend width? This [                             //charts[i].highcharts().legend.itemStyle.width = 150;
] works only after I hover over the legend text...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
chart.series[0].update({ name: "hello"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bL5ZM/149/